# Probably silly question on notation

Tags: limits, notation, soft-question, infinity

I just wanted to ask, since $\infty$ is not a number, if $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) \to \infty$ and also $\lim_{x \to b}f(x) \to \infty$, can we write $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$= $\lim_{x \to b}f(x)$?

Comment: Although $\pm\infty$ are not numbers, they are *points* on the extended real number line $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=[-\infty,\infty]$. (Infinities do not behave well algebraically, but they are perfectly fine when considered geometrically or topologically. And limit is a topological concept!) This legitimates equalities like $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$ or even $\infty = \infty$.

Comment: I mean, I am working in $\mathbb R$ and not $\overline {\mathbb R}$so…

Comment: Even when you are working with sequences/functions in $\mathbb{R}$, usually $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is adopted for defining infinite limits in the literature. Of course, you are free to choose to opt out of this convention, but then you will have to leave infinite limits undefined, rendering them uncomparable.

Comment: To begin with, you shouldn't write “$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \to \infty$”, but “$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \infty$” or “$f(x) \to \infty$ as $a \to \infty$”.

Comment: Oh thanks @HansLundmark, I always thought that it was the other way round and using ‘=‘ was wrong. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: Thanks @SangchulLee

Comment: The notation $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ stands for the limit itself, which is the number (or $\pm \infty$) that the function tends to. So the *limit* doesn't go anywhere, it's so to speak just sitting there waiting for $f(x)$ to come to it.

Comment: Ohh @HansLundmark I think you got it wrong. I used ‘=‘ for everything else and ‘$\rightarrow$’ only when the limit was $\pm \infty$.

Comment: What do you mean? The correct notations are “$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = A$” and “$f(x) \to A$ as $x \to a$”, regardless of whether $A \in \mathbb{R}$ or $A = \pm \infty$.

Comment: I would say the answer to your question depends on the particular textbook/person who grades your submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I am concluding this question.

- Previously, I used to write $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =c$ when c was finite, but $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)\rightarrow c$ when c tends to $\pm\infty$. For eg.,I’d write $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{sinx}{x}=1$ but $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}\rightarrow \infty$.
- Now, I have learned that I must use the notation $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}=\infty$, and not $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}\rightarrow \infty$. Please correct me if I have made some mistakes. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Such equation may be accepted in some context (for example stating something like $f(x)\leq g(x)\leq h(x)$ and $\lim f(x) = \lim h(x) \implies \lim f(x)= \lim g(x)$) but we need to be careful to avoid mistake by treating such equation as usual equation, for example subtracting two $\infty$s.

I make a remark about a related notion.
$\sin x = x+\omicron(x)\ (x→0)$ and $\tan(x)=x+\omicron(x)\ (x→0)$, but obviously $\sin x \neq \tan(x)$.