# Is infinity a limit?

Tags: limits, infinity

Say like $\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{x^2}$. My professor said the limit of a function
cannot be infinity, and according to my textbook “limit is a finite number” is clearly stated. Infinity, from my knowledge, is neither finite nor a number.

However I do see many people write down infinity as answer for questions like $\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{x^2}$.

I am confused. Which one is correct?

Comment: If the limit is infinite, then the limit doesn't exist. And $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}=+\infty $ is correct.

Comment: When we write $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = \infty$ that is not literally saying that the limit exists and is equal to infinity.  It is shorthand for saying "*as $x$ approaches zero the value of $\frac{1}{x^2}$ increases without bound*"

Comment: It is worth pointing out as well that there do exist contexts like the extended reals or the Riemann sphere that we could be working in where we *do* treat $\infty$ like a number (*albeit with a great deal of care*) in which case we do literally have the limit existing and being *equal* to infinity.  It is perhaps because of that why we use the notation we do for the usual scenario as well.

Comment: JMoravitz+1 The limit of a function *can* be infinity. A limit is *not* necessarily a finite number. If the limit is infinite, then the limit *does* "exist" (as an element of [$[-\infty, +\infty]$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line)).

Comment: As you can see from these comments, there is disagreement/ambiguity regarding the "existence" status of $\infty$. But one thing we can all agree on: $\infty$ is ***not a number***; and $\lim_{x \to 0} 1/x^2$ does *not exist* in the real numbers.

Comment: Nonetheless, one can formulate a rigorous definition of the expression $\lim_{x \to 0} 1/x^2 = \infty$, as hinted at in the answer of @JMoravitz.

Comment: Read here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4469433/probably-silly-question-on-notation

Comment: These statements should have been made with some qualification, such as "in this course" for the professor and "in this book" for the textbook. The textbook, especially, should have had a footnote about this issue. Another example of a restriction that can be changed in a later course is the following. In precalculus and beginning calculus courses the domain of $f(x) = \sqrt x$ (when not explicitly specified) is $x \geq 0.$ However, in complex variables courses the domain of $f(x) = \sqrt x$ (when not explicitly specified) is all complex numbers (including negative real numbers).

Comment: We should simply accept that the limit , strictly speaking , does not exist. I see no merit in extended real lines and similar trials to give "$\infty$" a meaning.

Comment: @Peter: Infinite limits are used in many investigations in real and complex analysis and, for what it's worth, in these investigations it's often not necessary to view $\infty$ as some kind of number that one might want to arithmetically work with. Many times, at least for real-valued functions, in stating results of interest it is enough to extend the usual order on the reals so that for each real number $r$ we have $-\infty < r < +\infty$ (and, of course, $-\infty < +\infty).$